# How might I have anticipated that $\frac14(\sqrt{5+2\sqrt5}+\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}})$ simplifies to a single surd (namely, $\frac14\sqrt{25+10\sqrt{5}}$)?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, area

This is perhaps a silly question related to calculating with surds. I was working out the area of a regular pentagon ABCDE of side length 1 today and I ended up with the following expression :

$$\frac{\sqrt{5+2\sqrt5}+\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}{4}$$

obtained by summing the areas of the triangles ABC, ACD and ADE.

I checked my solution with Wolfram Alpha which gave me the following equivalent expression :

$$\frac{\sqrt{25+10\sqrt{5}}}{4}$$

I was able to show that these two expressions are equivalent by squaring the numerator in my expression, which gave me

$$15+4\sqrt5+2\sqrt{70+30\sqrt5},$$

and then "noticing" that

$$\sqrt{70+30\sqrt5}=\sqrt{25+30\sqrt5+45}=5+3\sqrt5.$$
My question is the following : how could I have known beforehand that my sum of surds could be expressed as a single surd, and is there a way to systematize this type of calculation ? I would have liked to find the final, simplest expression on my own without the help of a computer.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I have no suggestion for how to anticipate the result, but a quick
way to verify it is
$$
(\sqrt5 - 1)^2(5 + 2\sqrt5) = (1 + 5 - 2\sqrt5)(5 + 2\sqrt5) =
10 + 2\sqrt5,
$$
whence
$$
\sqrt{10 + 2\sqrt5} = (\sqrt5 - 1)\sqrt{5 + 2\sqrt5} =
\sqrt{25 + 10\sqrt5} - \sqrt{5 + 2\sqrt5}.
$$

Comment: Interesting coincidence: I was working on something the other week, I forget what, and stumbled across a “double surd” that simplified nicely. (It might’ve been $\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{3}}$ simplifying to $\sqrt{3}-1$.) I noticed it because I thought its decimal expansion, 0.7320…, looked familiar! I prodded at it for a while and came up with a fairly unenlightening rule, something like “$\sqrt{a+2b\sqrt{c}}=b+\sqrt{c}$ where $a=b^2+c$”.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. There is a way to formalize this particular type of sum of square roots, similar to the way a determinant is developed for quadratic equations.

We can write the generic form of the expression in the first place as follows.

$\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{s}}+\sqrt{c+d\sqrt{s}}=\sqrt{x+y\sqrt{s}}$

Note that

1. $a, b, c, d, s$ are given and rational. We aim to express $x,y$ in terms of them.
2. The value in the double surds are identical, which are all $s$.
3. Only square roots are considered.

Then,

$(\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{s}}+\sqrt{c+d\sqrt{s}})^2=(\sqrt{x+y\sqrt{s}})^2$

$(a+c)+(b+d)\sqrt{s}+2\sqrt{(a+b\sqrt{s})(c+d\sqrt{s})}=x+y\sqrt{s}$

$2\sqrt{(a+c+bds)+(ad+bc)\sqrt{s}}=(x-a-c)+(y-b-d)\sqrt{s}$

$4(a+c+bds)+4(ad+bc)\sqrt{s}=(x-a-c)^2+(y-b-d)^2s+2(x-a-c)(y-b-d)\sqrt{s}$

Let $p=x-a-c,\ q=y-b-d$.

By comparing the coefficients in the rational and irrational terms,

$\begin{cases}
p^2+q^2s=4(a+c+bds)\\
pq=2(ad+bc)
\end{cases}$

By substituting $q=\frac{2(ad+bc)}{p}$ and $p=\frac{2(ad+bc)}{q}$ from the second equation to the first equation, we can get a formula for each of $p$ and $q$.

$\begin{cases}
p^4-4(ac+bds)p^2+4(ad+bc)^2s=0\\
sq^4-4(ac+bds)q^2+4(ad+bc)^2=0
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}
p^2=2[ac+bds\pm\sqrt{(ac+bds)^2-(ad+bc)^2s}]\\
q^2=\frac{2}{s}[ac+bds\pm\sqrt{(ac+bds)^2-(ad+bc)^2s}]
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}
p=\pm\sqrt{2[ac+bds\pm\sqrt{(ac+bds)^2-(ad+bc)^2s}]}\\
q=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{s}[ac+bds\pm\sqrt{(ac+bds)^2-(ad+bc)^2s}]}
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}
x=\pm\sqrt{2[ac+bds\pm\sqrt{(ac+bds)^2-(ad+bc)^2s}]}+(a+c)\\
y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{s}[ac+bds\pm\sqrt{(ac+bds)^2-(ad+bc)^2s}]}+(b+d)
\end{cases}$

As a result, there are three determinants to look at:

1. $D_1=(ac+bds)^2-(ad+bc)^2s$ has a rational square root.
2. $D_2=2(ac+bds\pm\sqrt{D_1})$ has a rational square root.
3. $D_3=\dfrac{D_2}{s}$ has a rational square root.

---

We can use the two surds that you dealt with as an example.

$a=5, b=2, c=10, d=2, s=5$

$D_1=(ac+bds)^2-(ad+bc)^2s=400$, which is a perfect square.

$D_2=2(ac+bds\pm\sqrt{D_1})=100\text{ or }180$. 100 is a perfect square.

$D_3=\dfrac{D_2}{s}=36\text{ or }20$. 36 is a perfect square.

Therefore, the two surds can be summed to a single surd.

As seen above, the determinants are much more complex than the quadratic formula. I wonder if anyone would memorize them like $(b^2-4ac)$.

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough analysis !

Answer (score 9):

$10 + 2 \sqrt 5$   has norm $100 - 5 \cdot 4 = 80.$  $5 + 2 \sqrt 5$   has norm $25 - 5 \cdot 4 = 5.$   The ratio of the norms is $\frac{80}{5} = 16,$  which is an integer and a square, so the ratio might be very nice.

$$ \frac{10+2 \sqrt 5}{5 + 2 \sqrt 5} \cdot \frac{5-2 \sqrt 5}{5 - 2 \sqrt 5} 
=   \frac{30-10 \sqrt 5}{5 }  = 6 - 2 \sqrt 5  $$

Next, $36 - 5 \cdot 4 = 16$  so $ 6 - 2 \sqrt 5 $  might be a square.  Indeed, by inspection it is $\left( 1 - \sqrt 5  \right)^2 =  \left(  \sqrt 5  - 1  \right)^2$    So  $10 + 2 \sqrt 5  = \left(  \sqrt 5  - 1  \right)^2 \left( 5 + 2 \sqrt 5 \right) $   and

$  \sqrt{10 + 2 \sqrt 5}  =  \left(  \sqrt 5  - 1  \right) \sqrt { 5 + 2 \sqrt 5  } $   Thus

$$  \sqrt{10 + 2 \sqrt 5} + \sqrt { 5 + 2 \sqrt 5  } =  \left(  \sqrt 5    \right) \sqrt { 5 + 2 \sqrt 5  } =  \sqrt { 25 + 10 \sqrt 5  }$$

$$ \color{red}{ \sqrt{10 + 2 \sqrt 5} + \sqrt { 5 + 2 \sqrt 5  } =   \sqrt { 25 + 10 \sqrt 5  } } $$

Comment: What "norm" are you using?

Comment: @enzotib $   a + b \sqrt 5    \; \; \mapsto \;   a^2 - 5 b^2  .$

Comment: Thank you, but I understood that without you explaining it. My question was more to be intended as: why do you call it norm? does this norm has a name? what type of properties can we deduce from this norm? (e.g. from the the ratio integer and square you deduce the ratio "may be" very nice)

Comment: Thank you for this, I was hoping to find some explanation in terms of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt5]$ and I like the thought process you used. It does yield a straightforward method to check if the sum can be simplified : take the quotient of the expressions inside the surds and check if it is a square of the form (A-1)^2.

Comment: @enzotib This is [quite standard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm).

Answer (score 2):

One way to (try to) simplify is squaring the sum and see where it leads. Then you get a product of radicals instead of a sum, and it's easier to simplify.

$$4A=\sqrt{5+2\sqrt5}+\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}$$
$$16A^2=15+4\sqrt5+2\sqrt{(5+2\sqrt5)(10+2\sqrt5)}$$
$$16A^2=15+4\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{70+30\sqrt5}$$

When you are here, there is a nested radical that you don't know how to deal with. It would be nice to write the radicand as a square. Let's try:

$$70+30\sqrt5=(a+b\sqrt5)^2=a^2+5b^2+2ab\sqrt5$$

Therefore, you must have

$$a^2+5b^2=70$$
$$2ab=30$$

Or equivalently

$$a^2+5b^2=70$$
$$5a^2b^2=5\times15^2=1125$$

Therefore, $a^2$ and $5b^2$ are the roots of the trinomial $t^2-70t+1125$.

The discriminant is $70^2-4\times1125=400$, a perfect square so it's going to be rather simple:

$$t=\frac{70\pm\sqrt{400}}{2}=\frac{70\pm20}{2}$$

That is, $t=25$ or $t=45$.

Therefore, either $a^2=25$ and $b^2=9$, or $a^2=45$ and $b^2=5$.
Both are correct, but only the first solution leads to integer $a$ and $b$ (however, the other solution leads after simplification to the same result): $a=\pm5$, $b=\pm3$. Now, the sign matters, from $2ab=30$ we know $a$ and $b$ must have the same sign. Since we are squaring it doesn't matter if they are both positive or both negative, but since we are going to take the square root of the square (i.e. absolute value), we may as well choose the positive values of $a$ and $b$.

Therefore, $70+30\sqrt5=(5+3\sqrt5)^2$, and

$$16A^2=15+4\sqrt5+2\times(5+3\sqrt5)=25+10\sqrt5$$

And

$$A=\frac14\sqrt{25+10\sqrt5}$$

---

In this specific case, you may get the expression for the area, by multiplying the apothem by the half-side by $10$:

If the apothem is $a$ and the side $c=1$, then $\tan\frac\pi5=\frac{c}{2a}$. Hence $a=\frac{c}{2\tan\frac\pi5}$ and the area $A=10a\frac c2=5ac=\frac{5}{4\tan\frac\pi5}$.

$$A=\frac{5}{4\tan\frac\pi5}=\frac{5\cos\frac\pi5}{4\sin\frac\pi5}=\frac{5(1+\sqrt5)}{4\sqrt{10-2\sqrt5}}=\frac{5(1+\sqrt5)\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}}{4\sqrt{80}}\\=\frac{5\sqrt{6+2\sqrt5}\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}}{16\sqrt5}=\frac{1}{16}\sqrt{30+10\sqrt5}\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}\\=\frac{1}{16}\sqrt{400+160\sqrt5}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{25+10\sqrt5}$$

Again, we got a product (and quotient) of radicals, and there are ways to simplify this.